# Child fragments not displayed properly on parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using nested fragments inside my activity,I have three fragments A, B, C where B and C is child fragment of A. Inside Fragment A's layout i want to give fragment B 60% and fragment C 40% of total device width respectively.Below is the layout of Fragment A:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.printer.epos.rtpl.NewOrderFragment"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@color/gray_background_color"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/bFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/cFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".4"/>
```

but when i run app on my device fragment B took 40% and C took 60% of total device width. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Try to change the layout_weight between your linearlayouts. So the first has .4 and the second has .6.Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes it is working @Vlad but sometimes problem still occurs.

Comment: Sometimes ?In what situations?